# Google Dart : How does .where() function work?

Tags: dart

```
var fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
fruits[0]; // apples
fruits.add('pears');
fruits.length == 4;
fruits.where((f) => f.startsWith('a')).toList();
```

The example in the documentation shows the above. 
I dont really understand the documentation of the method either.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.1/dart-collection/IterableMixin/where.html

I currently see a lambda function as a parameter inside where, with where having the argument f. What is f though? Im a bit confused.

It would be great if I could see a working example. As it stands now I dont really get it. I dont know how it works or what it really does apart from that it acts as some sort of filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is an anonymous function and `f` is the parameter it accepts

```
(f) => f.startsWith('a')
```

`where(...)` calls that passed function for each element in `fruits` and returns an iterable that only emits the values where the function returned `true`

`where(...)` is lazy, therefore the iteration and call of the passed function will only happen when the result is actually accessed, like with `.toList()`.

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/2d9d21de06eeee5605674bd1f8c6d3ce)

**update**

"anonymous" means the function has no name in contrary to a named function like

```
myFilter(f) => f.startsWith('a');

main() {
  fruits.where(myFilter).toList();
}
```

also

```
myFilter(f) => f.startsWith('a');
```

is just a shorter form of

```
myFilter(f) {
  return f.startsWith('a');
}
```

Comment: I dont really get it.  The lambda expression doesnt do anything as long as its not called. Does anonymous mean the same thing as in js? It calls itself?

Comment: I swear I tried it in dartpad, why does it work in your example. Hm got to check it out

Comment: I mean these collections  like where, intersection etc are really cool but its just for convenience right? I mean for example I can do what where can do with a simple if check: x[i][0] == 'a'

Comment: and I dont need to make a function call like in where.

Comment: Perfect explanation though.

Comment: `where()` is a method that you can "configure" with your custom filter function. Of course there are other ways. There are quite a lot of convenient methods that can easily be chained in a functional programming style like `fruits.where((f) => f.startsWith('a')).skip(1).take(2).map((f) => 'Do you want some $f?').forEach(print);`

Comment: Methods on `Stream` are quite similar, this often allows to write quite elegant code.

Comment: You are right. Holy crap but that is a huge gain in my workflow compared to javascript. Not to mention the async capabilities of Dart are insane

Comment: Sure, Dart is really nice, even out-of-the-box without any additional packages :)

Comment: Ya I told some of my colleagues at programming school and they only use dart now since the difference in workflow is really big. I just noticed es6 is like a cheap copy. No way im going back to js.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Just a little side question. Did things change by now or does dart still not support object literals (just maps)?

Comment: There are no object literals, just maps. I doubt this will change. Dart is not that dynamic.