# How to ignore some variables in a class when performing a search operation in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have a class in Dart for example

```
class Student{
 String name;
 int age;
 String grade;
}
```

And along with it I have a list of Student which are as follows

```
List<Student> students = [
  Student('Sam', 18, 'A'),
  Student('Mark', 20, 'B+'),
  Student('Moses', 18, 'A-'),
  Student('Ron', 18, 'B'),
];
```

I want to perform a search such that I ignore the name.

```
students.where(Student(IGNORE,18,'A'));
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a boolean predicate to the `.where` method in an anonymous function, and simply not search for the field to ignore.

```
List<Student> students = [
  Student('Sam', 18, 'A'),
  Student('Mark', 20, 'B+'),
  Student('Moses', 18, 'A-'),
  Student('Ron', 18, 'B'),
];

students.where((student) => (student.age==18 && student.grade=="A")); // Iterable containing Instance named Sam.
```

Will return an iterable with all instances of '''Student''' with an A and 18yo, regardless of name.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890394/google-dart-how-does-where-function-work) provides a more in depth explanation of how to filter with the `.where` method.